# Google Cloud Printing with Laravel not working

Tags: laravel-5.3, unauthorized, google-cloud-print

I am creating a code for printing my HTML view via Google Cloud Printing.

This is the package I am working with.

https://packagist.org/packages/bnbwebexpertise/laravel-google-cloud-print

I am getting "errorCode":8,"message":"User is not authorised."

```
$data = GoogleCloudPrint::asText()
            ->content('This is a test')
            ->printer("printer ID here")
            ->marginsInCentimeters(1, 1, 1, 1)
            ->send();
        return $data;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

https://www.google.com/cloudprint/#printers

Click on your printer, hit "Share" then share with the user you created. Based on the error message for you:

gcloud-print-138@iraqi-cinemas.iam.gserviceaccount.com